# Where can I find histograms and tables of prevalence of mutations in cancer?

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-expression, cancer

At some point in the past I found a cancer portal site which had aggregated data for the relationships between various mutations and their prevalence in cancer types and tumor data. The data was presented in various pleasantly coloured interactive histograms and you could search per-gene or per-disease.

However after spending a few hours, I cannot find the site again. Though I have found many sites with a great deal of data and nice visualizations.

The nearest looking site, was this one:
http://plugins.biogps.org/data_chart/data_chart.cgi?id=673

But that doesn't have the level of detail that I remember.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean [COSMIC](http://www.sanger.ac.uk/perl/genetics/CGP/cosmic?action=bygene&ln=BRCA1&start=1&end=1864&coords=AA%3aAA)? The [EBI Gene Expression Atlas](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/gene/ENSG00000012048) also has pretty charts, but now mutations.

Answer (score 1):

Your description sounds a lot like the [International Cancer Genome Consortium](https://icgc.org/)'s website. Choose a cancer and click your way to "Project Data" and you'll see some nicely covered histograms describing disease prevalence. You can also get mutation data among other things

Another good bet is the [cBio Portal](http://www.cbioportal.org/). If you click on "Data Sets" at the main page, you can choose a cancer and get various data in the "Study Summary" section including the prevalence of mutations within the study dataset.